# Prevent newline in (.md) files

Tags: github, markdown

How do I prevent newlines in the readme.md files (GitHub)?
We can always write the whole thing in one line to prevent it. But is there an exclusive tag/option to prevent the same, especially for tags that create newlines (headings) like span in html?

Comment: if your heading is too long to fit in screen width - it's bad header

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a space followed by a backslash do the concatenation you want? It does for me. That way I can break a paragraph into one sentence per line.

Comment: No it doesn't when you have HTML tags like <a></a> for instance. It breaks everything down